# Particle system ONGui() - Unity3d

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, camera, gameobject

I am developing a game in Unity3d and I have some scripts which uses OnGUI() method and they are attached to my GameMenu object. I need to play a particle system on the scene while the GUI scripts are active. When I do that I cant see the particle system because OnGUI method is disabling my MainCamera and is on top of everything on the scene.

So is there a way to play particle system in front of OnGUI() method ?

This is how my scene looks like:

[image]

On the red marked area, I want my particle system being played to underline the selection. But the whole menu is designed with OnGUI() method and my particle system is playing behind where I cant see.

Comment: Maybe a good move would be avoiding OnGui altogether it's pretty much deprecated.

Comment: Screenshots showing what you are trying to achieve, and how it goes wrong, would help

Comment: OnGui will always draw on top of everything.  I would explore something like the 2d toolkit from unikron to do this.  We  have used it for something similar and it worked great.

Comment: @tea yes but I have a lot of scripts using OnGui(), therefore I am not able to change the system.

Comment: @TylerDay thanks for your advice. It seems like as you say, there is no way to do this except using 3rd party tools.

Comment: Okay, what I don't understand is why GUI draw calls should obscure the whole scene behind. Is it an opaque GUI covering the whole screen? Which is why some kind of illustration would be helpful.

Comment: @tea I see what you mean :) Yes, the whole screen is covered with my menu background sprite which is drawn OnGUI() method. The background has no transparency. When I tried changing it, the scene didnt look good therefore it has to be opaque. I`ll post an image of the scene how it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using OnGui it's pretty deprecated. Unity supports this feature with its new GUI system. However, using OnGUI it is not possible (without using 3rd party tools).